# Хостинг и kohana

Tags: php, kohana

Поставил на хостинг kohana 3.2. Пишет

> `ErrorException [ 2 ]: mkdir(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 10583 is not allowed to access /var/www/vhosts/домен/httpdocs/application/logs/2012 owned by uid 503 ~ SYSPATH/classes/kohana/log/file.php [ 69 ]`

Хотя права /application/logs/ выставил 777.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, попросив выключить safe-mod на хостинге

Answer (score -1):

```
/var/www/vhosts/домен/httpdocs/application/logs/2012 //на эту папку
```

unix такая хитрая система, что то что вы назначили права верхней папке. не означает что они же применяться для дочерних :) возможно нужно использовать рекурсивную смену прав на каталог :)